# await/execute a function?

Tags: c#, task

My Start() has some really slow serial code so I figure i'll throw it into a task and await it.

```
await new Task(() => { c.Start(); });
```

This compiles however it appears it doesn't run the task unless i call Start(). Now instead of the simple one liner I have 3 lines. Is there a way I can write the below in one line?

```
var t = new Task(() => { c.Start(); });
t.Start();
await t;
```

Comment: `var t = new Task(() => { c.Start(); }); t.Start(); await t;` ?

Comment: Try this: `await Task.Run(c.Start)`. You should prefer `Task.Run` to manually constructing and starting anyway, because it performs some better optimizations behind the scenes.

Comment: @cory you should add that as an answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looking for `await Task.Run(c.Start)`. If you're on .NET 4.0 (rather than 4.5), you can use `await Task.Factory.StartNew(c.Start)`.

Prefer `Task.Factory.StartNew` to manually constructing/starting a `Task`, and `Task.Run` to `Task.Factory.StartNew`. Each one uses a more optimal implementation, and is not simply shorthand.